# Regular Expression to find specific words in lines. search() function

Tags: regex, python-3.x, search

I have a script to find specific words in lines. I have used regular Expression (search() in this case) to get a result as quickest as possible.

I am Looking for "NOMINAL" in row 2...

here you can find an extract from the .csv document:

```
<Set Name= Test>
    <TYPE NAME= Hello>
        <NOMINAL A= B= C= D= E= F= G=1.10 H=2.20 I=3.30 J=>
        <2ND_NOMINAL A= B= C= D= E= F= G=11.00 H=22.00 I=33.00>
```

And here is my script:

```
import itertools
import re


df = open('TESTSOV.csv')
for i,line in enumerate(itertools.islice(df, 0, 4)):
        if "TYPE=" in line:
            name.append(re.findall('NAME= (.*?\s)',line))
        if re.search(r"^NOMINAL",line):
            print(i,'v')
```

Output:

2 v

3 v

The search() function  returns line 2 (NOMINAL) and line 3 (2ND_NOMINAL).
How can i search for NOMINAL (only)?

I have also used "^" in front of Nominal ("^NOMINAL"), without any success…

Has somebody an idea?

regards,
B

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundries, change:

```
re.search(r"^NOMINAL",line):
```

To:

```
re.search(r"\bNOMINAL\b",line):
```